# is there a way to automatically import images?

Tags: import, photos

I'm making a photography portfolio website and i was wondering if there was a way to import all photos from a certain folder into their own separate divs?
Like for example right now I've just been importing using a lot of these:

```
<div class="fade">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="/Website/Pictures/Lanterns.jpg"><img src="/Website/Pictures/Lanterns.jpg" alt="Lanterns"</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I find it to be rather inefficient as if i want 20 pictures id have to make 20 of these. I was wondering if there was some way to import them all so that they each are contained in the two classes, but i dont have to improt them each separately?

Comment: When you say "import", do you mean that you want to generate HTML like the snippet you’ve given, but in greater quantity ?  If so, a script is one way to do it, such as bash or AppleScript (depending what system you’re running).

Comment: yes this is exactly what i mean. Theres no way to do this using javascript is there?

Comment: You can do it using any scripting or programming language you wish.  What system are you running ?  Windows, Mac, or some other ?

Comment: im using windows! windows 10 if that matters

Comment: I don't use Windows so can't offer a huge amount of help.  But you can use VBScript or Powershell to write a script that generates the HTML you want.  You could post a new question with this in mind, and add tags like [tag:VBScript], [tag:Powershell], [tag:Scripting], etc. to attract the right sort of help.  Good luck.